# Meteor Suddenly a lot of packages do not work (possible because of meteor update)

Tags: meteor

I;ve been developing a quizz app recently and it was working consistently but now suddenly a lot of packages are not defined. A small part of the error log below (this goes on to contain most of the packages)

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Package is not defined meteor.js?     7a66be7a03504cd2c18dd47b699e6233b60675ed:21
Uncaught ReferenceError: Package is not defined json.js?e22856eae714c681199eabc5c0710b904b125554:21
Uncaught ReferenceError: Package is not defined ejson.js?9ccd48dbafd805e21408c9eae1061468b3ec1f2f:21
Uncaught ReferenceError: Package is not defined logging.js?
```

Other interesting errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Deps is not defined quiz_list.js?b063b352079e20c9f9485683b352f8482a87fdf4:4
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined
```

Does anyone know what is causing this and how I can remedy it? I have tried resetting and updating.

Comment: Are you using `mrt`? I had similar problems just yesterday and got things back to work by running `mrt update`, and then restarting meteor.

Comment: For some reason rebooting my computer helped. tried mrt update and it indeed downloading new pacakeg updates so might also be a problem.

Comment: Had the same problem recently--went away after a series of project resets and reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

I often get a whole slew of these types of errors as a result of one uncaught exception right at the top. If things don't happen in the right order, then things really don't happen.

Try scrolling right up and seeing if there is a more informative error (not always shown in red in Chrome).